# Replacement for Resharper File Structure Window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, resharper

We are tired with Resharper bugginess in VS2013, and are trying out VS2017 Community without it to see whether Roslyn has brought enough to the table to make Resharper no longer essential.

Perhaps the most important feature for me is the File Structure Window, giving a nice overview of the current file in tree form. Does anyone have a good idea for a replacement? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some experimentation, I have found that [CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) has an excellent window called CodeMaid Spade, which so far seems better than File Structure.